# Handle Scrolling between full page section, with overflow:hidden on body

Tags: javascript

I would like to create exactly the same scrolling effect than tho one you can see on this website : http://blkboxlabs.com/

Do you have any idea how to implement it?

The problems I struggle with are:

- Detect scrolling when body has overflow:hidden on it.
- Handle one time event firing (when scroll is detected)

Comment: Here is my working solution after some work on it : It's working on all browsers and it's responsive : https://jsfiddle.net/6hs22Lc8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a simple way to do it. The body wraps the principal div that you can move with positioning absolute / fixed and top. You can detect mousewheel events with a jquery plugin.

The plugin: http://plugins.jquery.com/mousewheel/

The example code:

```
 <body>
    <div class="allcontent"></div>
 </body>
```

CSS

```
 body { overflow: hidden; }
 .allcontent {position: absolute; top:0; }
```

JS

```
 $('.allcontent').on('mousewheel', function(event) {
     console.log(event.deltaX, event.deltaY, event.deltaFactor);
 });
```

Good luck!

Comment: This helped me a lot to be able to detect "scroll" in spite of body set to overflow:hidden.
However, it fired many times, but a little flag solved it ;)

Comment: You can use a debounce to limit the event. Search about it. :)ç